# chaining regular expressing in python

Tags: python, regex, text-files

Hello I'm currently trying to parse a script that contains paths to files similar to the ones given below.  I would like to parse the file using regular expressions and store the data into a string with '\n' separation between files.  Example file given below.

```
    SAMPLE FILE: ('#' is a comment would like to keep commented out)
    add file -tls "../path1/path2/path3/example_1.edf"
    add file -tls "../path1/path2/path3/example_1.v"
    add file -tls "../path1/path2/path3/exa_4mple_1.sv"
    add file -tls "../path1/path2/path3/example_1.vh"        
    #add file -tls "../path1/path2/path3/exa_0mple_1.vhd"

    SAMPLE OUTPUT: (this example excludes the '\n' character)
    example_1.v
    exa_4mple_1.sv
    example_1.vh
    #exa_0mple_1.vhd
```

How can I construct the extension 're' so that it only includes the above extensions and excludes others?  I'm also wondering if it's possible to catch the '#' for commented out lines and prepend it the file name with a '#'.

```
    -Desired function:
    for match in re.finditer(r'/([A-Za-z0-9_]+\..+)"', contents):
       mylist.append(match.group(1))

    -Working Code: ( tested on the '.v' file case )
    re.finditer(r'/([A-Za-z0-9_]+\.v)"', contents)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are not needed:

```
>>> import os
>>> L = [
... "/path1/path2/path3/example_1.edf", 
... "/path1/path2/path3/example_1.v",
... "/path1/path2/path3/exa_4mple_1.sv", 
... "/path1/path2/path3/example_1.vh" ]
>>> for mypath in L:
...     if mypath.split('.')[-1] in ('v', 'sv', 'vh'):
...             print os.path.split(mypath)[1]
... 
example_1.v
exa_4mple_1.sv
example_1.vh
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
>>> [os.path.split(mypath)[1] 
... for mypath in L 
... if mypath.split('.')[-1] in ('v', 'sv', 'vh')]
['example_1.v', 'exa_4mple_1.sv', 'example_1.vh']
```

Comment: Perhaps I worded my question poorly.  The variable contents was used in a "contents = file_obj.read()" on a very large script containing all kinds of garbage inner mixed with the files who's paths vary.  I'm confused about where the path formatting occurred.

Comment: @MattCarlis Is the whole file's contents just the paths? Because then you could do something like `file_obj.read().split('\n')`

Comment: No the file is a very large script with thousands of paths inner mixed with calls to other scripts, tools, makefile components, etc!

Comment: @MattCarlis I'm not sure about that, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want ? :

```
import re

contents = '''
add file -tls "../path1/path2/path3/example_1.edf"
add file -tls "../path1/path2/path3/example_1.v"
add file -tls "../path1/path2/path3/exa_4mple_1.sv"     
add file -tls "../path1/path2/path3/example_1.vh"     
#add file -tls "../path1/path2/path3/exa_0mple_1.vhd"
'''

print contents

pat = "^(#?)add file.+?\"\.\./(?:\w+/)*(\w+?\.\w*v\w*)\"\s*$"

gen = (''.join(mat.groups())
       for mat in re.finditer(pat,contents,re.MULTILINE))

print '\n'.join(gen)
```

The pattern allows to catch paths with extensions containing the letter 'v', that's waht I understood from your question.
I also put the string `add file` as a criterium of catching, according to your example.
I used `\w` in the pattern.
With this pattern, all paths are supposed to begin with `../`
If all these characteristcs aren't adapted to your case, we'll change what needs to be changed.

Note that I put `\s*` at the end of the pattern, in case there are whitespaces in the line after the path.

Comment: Are you sure this is working code?  For some reason I'm getting errors!

Comment: What errors ? If you don't say them, I can't guess. - Do you use Python 3 ?

Comment: I'm using 2.7.5.  I'm getting an error on the for mat in re.finditer(pat,contents,re.MULTILINE)`) line.  It's highlighting the trailing ( ' ) after the MULTILINE).

Comment: You really need someone else to find what to do to correct ? On your opinion, if the trailing (') is highlighted, it is to signal what ?

Comment: Whatever dude I tried a number of different things with your code.  I got my original code to do what I wanted.  Thanks for your attempt anyways.